# ExtJS 4 cell edit for treePanel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to use `Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing` plugin for `tree.Panel` but it doesn't work.
It works OK for grid.Panel but not for tree...

Clicking on cell doesn't have any effect...

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing

Answer (score 1):

[I found a workaround here:](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?131602-4.0.0-Cellediting-on-TreeGrid)

Comment: Please [provide some context for the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer)